I want to remove controller name from URL in ASP.NET MVC
I created an area with the name of Member in ASP.NET MVC. I also created two controllers in this area, AccountController and DashboardController.
In the DashboardController, I have 3 methods which are Index, MemberList and Create.
While I run the  project and go to the Member area, the URL looks like this:
https://localhost:44394/Member/Dashboard

While I go to MemberList page, the URL is like this:
https://localhost:44394/Member/Dashboard/MemberList

I want to remove the Dashboard controller name from the URL. What should I do?
This is my code in RouteConfig file:
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); 

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);


In your MemberAreaRegistration class, you can define the route rule/constraint for DashboadController without the controller name path: Member/{action}/{Id}.
Ensure this route rule/constraint is applied before the default route rule/constraint.
public class MemberAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Member_Dashboard",
            "Member/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "Member_default",
            "Member/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}


So, do I have to write this way for all the controllers I create, or will there be a common method for all controllers?

Hmmm, from your question you mention the DashboardController from Member Area. I am not sure of the definition of all your controllers.

If you want to remove the controller name from the route for all controllers, you can set the default route in the RouteConfig to "{action}/{Id}". For the controller in areas, you need to edit the default path to "/{action}/{Id}" in your AreaRegistration classes. Just my concern is you need to be careful especially when there is same action name in different controllers.
